# Nexus 3 upgrade failed: Missing recipe: apt-hosted

Tags: nexus, sonatype

I'm trying to upgrade the Nexus installation from `3.12.x` to the latest `3.15.2`, which would seem like an easy task.

I have followed the [upgrade guide](https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000350007?_ga=2.142199601.2045160094.1553775672-1372588150.1553775672):

- Updated the `nexus.rc` file
- Updated the `nexus.vmoptions` file

To match the previous version.

However the `nexus run` command is giving me all kinds of Exceptions which is making this very difficult:

```
ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.repository.manager.internal.RepositoryManagerImpl - Failed transition: NEW -> STARTED
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Missing recipe: apt-hosted
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:585)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.manager.internal.RepositoryManagerImpl.recipe(RepositoryManagerImpl.java:155)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.manager.internal.RepositoryManagerImpl.newRepository(RepositoryManagerImpl.java:173)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.manager.internal.RepositoryManagerImpl.restoreRepositories(RepositoryManagerImpl.java:264)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.manager.internal.RepositoryManagerImpl.doStart(RepositoryManagerImpl.java:246)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.StateGuardLifecycleSupport.start(StateGuardLifecycleSupport.java:67)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.MethodInvocationAction.run(MethodInvocationAction.java:39)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.StateGuard$TransitionImpl.run(StateGuard.java:193)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.TransitionsInterceptor.invoke(TransitionsInterceptor.java:56)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.extender.NexusLifecycleManager.startComponent(NexusLifecycleManager.java:168)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.extender.NexusLifecycleManager.to(NexusLifecycleManager.java:100)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.extender.NexusContextListener.frameworkEvent(NexusContextListener.java:195)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1429)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The system is running CentOS, but i am not sure why it's trying to use `apt`.

Whenever i'm pointing the data-directory to a empty dir, `nexus run` will successfully complete and works as expected, but obviously all the users/repositories are lost.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 2):

it looks like the plugin **nexus-repository-apt** isn't installed on your version. make sure to install https://github.com/sonatype-nexus-community/nexus-repository-apt. The steps to install this plugin are writen into the readme of the plugin.

I think after that then nexus will work again :)

Comment: That format/plugin doesn't ship with default NXRM 3.15.

Answer (score 0):

Update 2019: Sonatype included apt repository type since Nexus release: 3.17.0
no manual installation of the plugin anymore. works out of the box.